# apt-get aborts after I type Y to continue

Tags: apt, package-management, gnome-terminal

After I use `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` to check for updates via terminal, there's a small but weird problem. After I answer Y, I expect it to download and install updates. Strangely, it instead aborts.

```
...
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Translation-en_US
Fetched 594 kB in 1min 29s (6.649 B/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-3.0 gir1.2-webkit-3.0 libegl1-mesa libegl1-mesa-drivers libgbm1 libgl1-mesa-dri libgl1-mesa-glx libglapi-mesa
  libgles2-mesa libjavascriptcoregtk-1.0-0 libjavascriptcoregtk-3.0-0 libopenvg1-mesa libwayland-egl1-mesa libwebkitgtk-1.0-0
  libwebkitgtk-1.0-common libwebkitgtk-3.0-0 libwebkitgtk-3.0-common libxatracker2 ubuntu-drivers-common
Need to get 24,1 MB of archives.
After this operation, 422 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Abort.
```

Original screenshot: [apt-get abort](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3UKu.png)

What could be the reason for this, and how can I fix it?

Comment: That happens sometimes when you have a slow internet connection, and there is a lot of new packages to be installed.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you running? Can you try `sudo bash -c 'apt-get update && apt-get -y dist-upgrade'`

Comment: Can you try `O` (from `Oui`) instead of `Y`? I've had it in the past when had installed other locales.

Comment: @don.joey Weird that it wouldn't show the French prompt: `Souhaitez-vous continuer ? [O/n]`

Answer (score 1):

This can also happen (or happens with a higher frequency) if you wait a couple of minutes before typing 'Y'. In case it happens just repeat the command and it will run fine.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the interface was showing S/n (Spanish for Sí/no (Yes/no)), I typed "S" and the abort state was get. When typed "Y" the apt-get continue ok with its process. This is similar to comment from don.joey but with Spanish instead of French.