# Why am I unable to install python-gtk on my Ubuntu 16.04.1?

Tags: apt, python

When I try to install `python-gtk2-dev`, I get this message:

```
~$ sudo apt-get install python-gtk2-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libpaps0 linux-headers-4.4.0-51 linux-headers-4.4.0-51-generic
  linux-headers-4.4.0-52 linux-headers-4.4.0-52-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-53
  linux-headers-4.4.0-53-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-57
  linux-headers-4.4.0-57-generic linux-image-4.4.0-51-generic
  linux-image-4.4.0-52-generic linux-image-4.4.0-53-generic
  linux-image-4.4.0-57-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-51-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-52-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-53-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-57-generic linux-signed-image-4.4.0-51-generic
  linux-signed-image-4.4.0-52-generic linux-signed-image-4.4.0-53-generic
  linux-signed-image-4.4.0-57-generic paps snap-confine
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  docbook-xsl libffi-dev libpython-dev libpython2.7-dev python-dev
  python-gobject-2-dev python-gtk2-doc python2.7-dev
Suggested packages:
  dbtoepub docbook-xsl-doc-html | docbook-xsl-doc-pdf | docbook-xsl-doc-text
  | docbook-xsl-doc docbook-xsl-saxon fop libsaxon-java libxalan2-java
  libxslthl-java xalan
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  docbook-xsl libffi-dev libpython-dev libpython2.7-dev python-dev
  python-gobject-2-dev python-gtk2-dev python-gtk2-doc python2.7-dev
0 upgraded, 9 newly installed, 0 to remove and 32 not upgraded.
Need to get 30.6 MB of archives.
After this operation, 72.6 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Abort.
```

What should I do?

Comment: When promted with `Do you want to continue? [Y/n]`, you typed `Y`, did you press Enter after that?

Comment: Yes ,I  type y and then I pressed enter key.

Comment: Run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` first, and try again. Also, kind of a silly question but, you have more than those 73 MB of free space, right?

Comment: Yes I have more than specified space.

Comment: Duplicate question with no answers... http://askubuntu.com/questions/476167/apt-get-abort-after-i-type-y-to-continue

Comment: Do you have other locales installed providing languages besides english? Do you get the same result if you try again?

Comment: What's the output of `lsb_release -a` ? My assumption is that @M.Becerra is correct. Most of us are already updated to 16.04.2

Comment: I just used ,sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade  then I cleared some package although I had sufficient space and finally  I get  the positive result.Thanks to all of you specially M. Becerra .

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if this is your solution, but it has happen to me before when I copy paste a command into the terminal. Solution for me was to simply type it by myself.

Comment: sorry but how is this better than copying and pasting the command ?

Comment: I don't know, I would have explained if I knew. The fact that it worked for me might give "hope" that it works for other people.

Comment: @Nicholas The only way I see this working is if the copied command had a typo that you subconsciously repaired when you typed i in. Do you think that's possible?

Comment: might be, but I wouldn't say so. I as same as baponkar got the output that is produced after the correct command is entered. It might have something if in a scenario paste a command, and that creates some whitespace before the y