# My command gets aborted when typing Y

Tags: wireless

Hy Guys I am pretty new to all this so please be patient. I tried everything from y over Y, yes, Yes to YES. Retrying doesn't help as I tried it 30 times.

```
jan@Jan-Network:~$ sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  dpkg-dev fakeroot g++ g++-7 gcc gcc-7 libalgorithm-diff-perl libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl libalgorithm-merge-perl libasan4 libc-dev-bin
  libc6-dev libcilkrts5 libfakeroot libgcc-7-dev libitm1 libmpx2 libquadmath0 libstdc++-7-dev libubsan0 linux-generic
  linux-headers-4.15.0-124 linux-headers-4.15.0-124-generic linux-image-4.15.0-124-generic linux-image-generic linux-libc-dev
  linux-modules-4.15.0-124-generic linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-124-generic make manpages-dev
Suggested packages:
  debian-keyring g++-multilib g++-7-multilib gcc-7-doc libstdc++6-7-dbg gcc-multilib autoconf automake libtool flex bison gcc-doc
  gcc-7-multilib gcc-7-locales libgcc1-dbg libgomp1-dbg libitm1-dbg libatomic1-dbg libasan4-dbg liblsan0-dbg libtsan0-dbg libubsan0-dbg
  libcilkrts5-dbg libmpx2-dbg libquadmath0-dbg glibc-doc libstdc++-7-doc fdutils linux-doc-4.15.0 | linux-source-4.15.0 linux-tools make-doc
Recommended packages:
  thermald
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  build-essential dpkg-dev fakeroot g++ g++-7 gcc gcc-7 libalgorithm-diff-perl libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl libalgorithm-merge-perl libasan4
  libc-dev-bin libc6-dev libcilkrts5 libfakeroot libgcc-7-dev libitm1 libmpx2 libquadmath0 libstdc++-7-dev libubsan0
  linux-headers-4.15.0-124 linux-headers-4.15.0-124-generic linux-image-4.15.0-124-generic linux-libc-dev linux-modules-4.15.0-124-generic
  linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-124-generic make manpages-dev
The following packages will be upgraded:
  linux-generic linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic
3 upgraded, 29 newly installed, 0 to remove and 43 not upgraded.
Need to get 89.1 MB of archives.
After this operation, 363 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] yes
Abort.
jan@Jan-Network:~$
```

and here also

```
jan@Jan-Network:~$ sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r) git
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
linux-headers-4.15.0-123-generic is already the newest version (4.15.0-123.126).
linux-headers-4.15.0-123-generic set to manually installed.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  dpkg-dev fakeroot g++ g++-7 gcc gcc-7 git-man libalgorithm-diff-perl libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl libalgorithm-merge-perl libasan4
  libc-dev-bin libc6-dev libcilkrts5 liberror-perl libfakeroot libgcc-7-dev libitm1 libmpx2 libquadmath0 libstdc++-7-dev libubsan0
  linux-libc-dev make manpages-dev
Suggested packages:
  debian-keyring g++-multilib g++-7-multilib gcc-7-doc libstdc++6-7-dbg gcc-multilib autoconf automake libtool flex bison gcc-doc
  gcc-7-multilib gcc-7-locales libgcc1-dbg libgomp1-dbg libitm1-dbg libatomic1-dbg libasan4-dbg liblsan0-dbg libtsan0-dbg libubsan0-dbg
  libcilkrts5-dbg libmpx2-dbg libquadmath0-dbg git-daemon-run | git-daemon-sysvinit git-doc git-el git-email git-gui gitk gitweb git-cvs
  git-mediawiki git-svn glibc-doc libstdc++-7-doc make-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  build-essential dpkg-dev fakeroot g++ g++-7 gcc gcc-7 git git-man libalgorithm-diff-perl libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl libalgorithm-merge-perl
  libasan4 libc-dev-bin libc6-dev libcilkrts5 liberror-perl libfakeroot libgcc-7-dev libitm1 libmpx2 libquadmath0 libstdc++-7-dev libubsan0
  linux-libc-dev make manpages-dev
0 upgraded, 27 newly installed, 0 to remove and 46 not upgraded.
Need to get 31.8 MB of archives.
After this operation, 148 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Abort.
```

Comment: Type `y` and press Enter.

Comment: Try some of the suggestions here https://askubuntu.com/questions/476167/apt-get-aborts-after-i-type-y-to-continue

Comment: Try pressing only the enter key. The uppercase Y indicates that it is the default answer.

Comment: or you can try the "-y" option on your command line to skip the system from asking for confirmation. Check  your local system languages. You may need to reply the first letter of "yes" in your own language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
sudo apt-get install <package> -y
```

The -y flag means yes.

Comment: This is an effective temporary workaround. However the underlying problem (perhaps locales) is unresolved and will continue to bite the user in other ways..

Comment: To upgrade and skipping to skip confirmation you can also run `sudo apt-get install <package> -y`, to remove packages `sudo apt-get purge <package> -y` and to purge   packages  `sudo apt-get purge <package> -y`